# get the generation number and pass it to the fitness function PyGAD

Tags: python, optimization, genetic-algorithm, pygad

I am trying to set up the fitness function in PyGAD but inside this I am calling and external process for each solution(individual) get the resulting data and perform the fitness. So I'll have a folder for each generation and each individual for each process execution, I can get the individual number with the solution_idx but I want the generation number so i can create the folders with each index (generation and individual).
The format for a fitness function in PyGAD documentation is:

```
def fitness_func(solution, solution_idx):
    #perform fitness
    return fitness
```

For what I want it would look something like this:

```
def fitness_func(solution, solution_idx,ga_instance):

    generation=ga_instance.generation_completed

    data=function2callprocess(solution,solution_idx,generation)

    fitness=fitness(data)

    return fitness
```

so the function2callprocess needs the solution index and generation number to keep track of the GA so it creates the folders or each run of the process.

I wonder if this is possible or anybody had any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for using [PyGAD](https://pygad.readthedocs.io/), Maria :)

Based on your question, you need to pass 3 parameters instead of just 2 to the fitness function where the third parameter is the current generation number.

Because PyGAD expects the fitness function to only have 2 parameters, you cannot pass a third parameter. But it is super easy to work around it.

You already know that the current generation number can be accessed through the `generations_completed` property of the `pygad.GA` instance. If the instance is `ga_instance`, then we can access this parameter using:

```py
ga_instance.generations_completed
```

Based on the fact that the fitness function is only called after an instance of the `pygad.GA` class is created, then we can use this instance inside the fitness function to access the `generations_completed` attribute.

This is how the fitness function should be. The trick is accessing the global variable `ga_instance` which is defined outside the fitness function. You can read [this article](https://medium.com/@ahmedfgad/python-scopes-and-the-legb-rule-d37bf3277e2c) for more information about global variables in Python.

```py
def fitness_func(solution, solution_idx):
    global ga_instance

    print("generations_completed", ga_instance.generations_completed)

    # fitness = ...

    return fitness
```

This is a complete example which generates random fitness values. Just edit the fitness function to calculate the fitness properly.

```py
import pygad
import random

def function2callprocess(solution, solution_idx, generation_number):
    return random.random()

def fitness_func(solution, solution_idx):
    global ga_instance

    print("generations_completed", ga_instance.generations_completed)

    generation = ga_instance.generations_completed

    data = function2callprocess(solution, solution_idx, generation)

    # fitness = ...
    fitness = data

    return fitness

last_fitness = 0
def on_generation(ga_instance):
    global last_fitness
    print("Generation = {generation}".format(generation=ga_instance.generations_completed))
    print("Fitness    = {fitness}".format(fitness=ga_instance.best_solution(pop_fitness=ga_instance.last_generation_fitness)[1]))
    print("Change     = {change}".format(change=ga_instance.best_solution(pop_fitness=ga_instance.last_generation_fitness)[1] - last_fitness))
    last_fitness = ga_instance.best_solution(pop_fitness=ga_instance.last_generation_fitness)[1]

ga_instance = pygad.GA(num_generations=5,
                       num_parents_mating=5,
                       sol_per_pop=10,
                       num_genes=2,
                       fitness_func=fitness_func,
                       on_generation=on_generation)

ga_instance.run()

ga_instance.plot_fitness()

solution, solution_fitness, solution_idx = ga_instance.best_solution(ga_instance.last_generation_fitness)
print("Solution", solution)
print("Fitness value of the best solution = {solution_fitness}".format(solution_fitness=solution_fitness))
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed thank you for your answer, that makes a lot of sense. Are you defining a global last fitness variable as well and setting it up to zero because you are calling the ga_instance inside the fitness function? I am trying to make sense of the use of that last fitness global variable.

Comment: Hi Maria. No, I just defined the last_fitness variable outside the function to hold the fitness value of the last generation. This way I can see the difference between the current fitness and the old fitness in the last generation. This helps to know if there is a progress.